# Can I somehow download or aquire the discord css file?

Tags: css, discord

I would like to create a website to go hand in hand with my discord bot. I thought it would look nice, if they similar styling, to keep the whole thing more as a unit(I would also not have to worry about button-, checkbox-, etc. styles). As an example, I would like my buttons to have the typical discord-appearance of the blue button with white text and rounded edges(I assume you use dark mode). I of course did some research myself, but couldnt find a library or a standalone css-file that includes all the styles. So my question to you is: do you know a library or link that includes the css-stylesheet? Could I copy the stylesheet from the official discord-websites source-code alternatively?

I am thankful for every suggestion! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this chrome extension to download all the source files for a webpage:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-all-resources/abpdnfjocnmdomablahdcfnoggeeiedb?hl=en

The files would be downloaded into a .zip file. You can then extract it's contents and get the CSS file

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I added the extension, but cannot get it to work for the life of me. I know it has instructions when I click the icon, but I do not understand what to do next. It mentions a "developer panel", but I do not have any idea which panel is referenced there. Mind giving me some advice? That would be really great :)

Comment: Oh nevermind, just found out that the console is referenced... Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad you figured it out